# Postgresql relation does not exist

Tags: postgresql, rds

I am connecting to my PostgreSQL DB on AWS RDS through SQL workbench. i have created a new table. it created successfully. table name is like public.xyz.
Now when i am trying to access the select query on 'public.xyz' i am getting error like

```
'Relation public.xyz does not exist'.
```

i have checked that my show_path contains %user,public. no case issue.

i have tried select query like select * from public.xyz  and select * from xyz etc.. all have same issue

please suggest.

Comment: does sql workbench show you a list of schemas, and each table inside each schema?

Comment: it show public schema. but when i select TABLE under that. its an empty list.

Comment: do you have the correct permissions on this table ?

Comment: i created the table with same user with which i opened connection for select query. do i need to explicitly give permission after creation ?

Comment: I have heard cases where ownership can not be assigned correctly. Are you connecting as a super user ? if not then i believe that is your answer. I would guess its to do with the AWS connection, but i'm no expert there. Grant yourself permission as a walk around.

Comment: i will try this. thanks,

Comment: Check ownership. Out of interest what is the users permissions ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138242/discussion-between-mokadillion-and-geekintown).

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be a problem with SQL workbench. when i tried to create table using psql client on a linux machine, it worked properly. now i am able to run the same select query which was failing earlier. don't know inner details, but it seems to be an issue with SQL workbench.